# Facebook Graph API - Subscribe a specific app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to subscribe a specific app to a Facebook page. I can do so by posting to this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/{page_id}/subscribed_apps
```

But when I do so it subscribes the Graph API Explorer and I want to subscribe my App. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a Page Token created with YOUR App, not a Page Token created by the Graph API Explorer App. Select your App in the API Explorer before Login and before getting the Page Token with `/me/accounts`.